# Why is my div populated with my whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I'm trying to load a div from another page using ajax but maintain the URL integrity using the History API. The ajax and history part is working (ie. the div is loading and the url is changing) but for some reason my div contains my entire page not just what is meant to be in the div!

This is the case for both the original page and the page div being loaded.

Stripped back HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="slider">
        ... all the page content
        <a rel='tab' href="p/password.jsf">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){

            //get the link location that was clicked
            pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

            //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
            $.ajax({
                url:pageurl + '?rel=tab',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#slider').html(data);
                }});

            //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
            if(pageurl!=window.location){
                window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
            }
            return false;  
        });
    });

    /* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without reload*/
    $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',
            success: function(data){
                $('#slider').html(data);
            }});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: because ajax reads the page response (which is the full page) .. so the response for ajax is whats in the page sort of WYSIWYG thingy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch an part of an page with ajax, then you can use the `load` method with the `id` of the element to fetch the content from.

```
$('#slider').load(pageurl + '?rel=tab #container_with_content_to_fetch', function() {
  alert('callback after success.');
});
```

More info about `load()`: [info](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Thanks Sven thats exactly what was needed. How can I achieve the same result for the popstate? At the moment I am using `$('#slider').load(location.pathname);` but on the original page load that is populating the #slider div with the entire page. I tried `$('#slider').load(location.pathname + '#slider');` but doesn't like that.

Comment: No problemo! You need an space between the `url` and `id`: `$('#slider').load(location.pathname + ' #slider');`

Comment: That has cancelled out the effect and just treats the link as a normal link by loading the whole page again.

Comment: Ok just tried it on my machine and you need the space between the url and id. I think you need to disable the default link action as isherwood described `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't seem to like it with or without the `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Maybe it's an element under the link? try adding `e.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to stop the default click action. It appears as though your link is acting as a... link.

```
$("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you if you want to select a specific part of the page that you recive with the ajax response 
then do the following

```
   /* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without reload*/
    $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',
            success: function(data){
               var mydiv = $('#my_div_id' , data ) // this will get the div with an id of #my_div_id
                $('#slider').html(mydiv );
            }});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` loads the whole page. You can use `.load()`

Instead of

`$.ajax({
                url:pageurl + '?rel=tab',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#slider').html(data);
                }});`

you can use

`$('#slider').load(pageurl + ' [rel=tab]');`

The docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).